# Changes to iptable blocked all the ports, hence unable to connect to this Amazon EC2 instance through putty

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables

Yesterday I was working on blocking of access to Redis server from out side doing by doing some changes to "iptable" file, unfortunately it blocked all the port which includes port 80 and 22 also, Hence I was unable to connect to EC2 instance from putty. Will you tell me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598

I hope you are using EBS and not ephemeral storage. You know you could have used EC2 Security Groups instead of iptables, and then you could have easily fixed your mistake.